# How to do unit test for HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath

Tags: asp.net, unit-testing

I'm using `HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath()` in my method to fetch document.

To write unit test for this method,

What do I have to do in:

1. App.config
2. In my unit test method

How do I Mock this?

I subjected to do a unit test only for `Current.Server.Mappath()` not for `Path.Combine()`

Comment: Since `MapPath` involves the web server and the file system, this isn't really a unit test and realistically your only option here is trying to Mock HttpContext.Current - which is not a pleasant task nor recommended...is there a reason why you cannot change the code? What's the method you are unit testing - can you explain its function - perhaps there is a better way to structure it that's more condusive to being unit tested.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unit testing for Server.MapPath](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19563106/unit-testing-for-server-mappath)

Comment: @Liam not really as the other question was asked after this one! So the other is a duplicate of this if anything :) Granted it's the same person, but short term memory loss is out of the realms of SO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is typical with code that calls static methods, it's very difficult to test while preserving separation of concern and avoiding tight coupling. Here is a generic approach to test and mock "untestable code": write a "facade wrapper" to it.

- Create a wrapper for these methods. A simple class that contains methods named sensibly, and only delegates to the untestable calls (typically static calls)
- Create an interface to that wrapper class
- Instead of directly calling the untestable methods in your client code, use the wrapper (dependency-injected using the interface provided in step 2) and call normal methods on it.
- In your unit-test, mock the wrapper with the behaviour you want.

This approach effectively reduces the coupling and separates the concerns that need to be separated. Of course, you still can't test the behaviour of the wrapper itself, but if it's simple enough (only delegating to the original calls) then it's not as big a problem.

Comment: This is actually a very good answer, however it's not easy to understand for people who don't know what a dependency-injection means. That's probably why the other one got more upvotes... you should probably provide some plain and simple code example.

Answer (score 9):

Probably the best solution is to avoid using `Server.MapPath`: for example, you can replace:

```
Server.MapPath("~/MyFolder/MyFile.dat")
```

by:

```
Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, @"MyFolder\MyFile.dat")
```

Comment: I can't do code change. I subjected to test only. Not to change. How to do for the code I mentioned

Comment: This did not work for my case. the unit test is located in a different project.

Comment: @Terence, one way to handle this is to include the relevant file(s) in your unit test project as a link, with "Copy to output folder" set to true.

Answer (score 0):

This is my suggestion:

In your app:

```
  {...
         var destinationPath= IOHelper.MapPath(DatafeedFolderName);
    ...
  }
```

This is the code of the help method

```
public static string MapPath(string subFolder)
                {
                    return HttpContext.Current.IsNull()
                        ? Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), subFolder)
                        : HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(subFolder);
                }
```

And the unit test can use:

```
 {...
     Assert.True(runtime_path, Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\destimationPath"
...}
```